# ANTLR syntactic predicates for JAVACC

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar, javacc

In ANTLR, we can use [syntactic predicates](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar) to solve certain issues as follows. This is just a simple example.

```
a : (L K)=> b
   | c
   ;

b : L K
   ;

c : L M
   ;
```

What I want to know is how to achieve the same thing in JAVACC? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept called SYNTACTIC LOOKAHEAD in javacc. You can use that to achieve same behavior.

For an example assume your grammar rule is as follows.
    void Expr():
    {}
    {
       Call () | Var()
    }

If you need to do a lookahead of unknown times then you can for something like

```
void Expr():
{}
{
LOOKAHEAD(Call())
Call () | Var()
}
```

For more information please refer http://javacc.java.net/doc/lookahead.html